# What should a student do if a professor agrees to write recommendation, then retracts offer upon realizing he confused the student with someone else?

Tags: etiquette, recommendation-letter

Prof. Z has taught thousands of students in my former school since 2010. In the Biology course that he taught, there were two students (A and B) with similar full names and nicknames, but their academic results were totally different. 
Prof. Z liked student A but hated student B because student B used to be very naughty in Prof. Z's courses and got very bad grades.

On January 4th, Prof. Z received student B's email for a letter of recommendation. Prof. Z agreed to do so and arranged a time to meet student B. On the day when they met, Prof. Z knew he had made a big mistake, and he refused to do anything for student B.
Given that situation, what would you do if this happened to you (as student B)? This really happened recently in my former school, and student B was very angry and made a complaint to the head of Prof. Z's department.

Comment: Wow that must have been awkward for both parties.

Comment: While I agree that this is kinda awkward, what in ${deity}'s name did B complain about? "He promised me a letter, and after figuring out that I was horrible in his course [something that I of course knew] he retracted his offer rather than writing a bad letter"?

Comment: *"Given that situation, what would you do if this happened to you (as student B)?"* Be happy that Z did *not* write a letter, specifically pointing out how B was  hoping to get away with this misunderstanding that he presumably knew about (otherwise, why ask a Prof. where you did horribly in class in the first place?).

Comment: Yes, even if you give the student the benefit of the doubt regarding the misunderstanding (and whether he was deliberately trying to take advantage of it), the alternative would be for Prof. Z to write a short letter saying "B was very naughty in my course and got very bad grades, and I assume that's not what you are looking for."  That would waste Z's time and hurt B's application, so not writing a letter is better for everyone.

Comment: Student B has some issues...

Comment: As B? Use it as a lesson not to ask for a letter of recommendation from a prof in whose course I made a fool out of myself. Seriously, as prof I wouldn't have dreamed that the bad student would ask for a letter of recommendation, so of course I would have assumed it was the good student. The prof did nothing wrong, B acted wrong in the course and by asking for the letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Student B, I would be pretty mad about this, even more than if he had declined to write me a letter in the first place.  But I would also recognize that it was for the best (if he hadn't done this, he would have written me a bad letter).

Also, I would never have gone to the department head about this because

1. It's not something that merits a formal complaint
2. It's not something I'd want to be known for, especially among other professors who may be writing my letters of recommendation.

Comment: I don't understand how a sane student could be made about this situation! Could there have been any reasonable expectation that the prof would write a _positive_ letter based on bad behavior and bad performance? A @DanielWessel commented, most likely the prof figured it was the other (good...) student of the same name.

Comment: (1) The professor said he would do something for B and didn't.  (2) B may not have known about the student A with the same name, and therefore believed that the professor was genuinely willing to write the letter (after all, he said he would).  (3) B may not have expected a stellar letter, but still thought his letter would be better than the other letters he could have secured.

Comment: Making clerical errors does not absolve a professor of being a decent human being.  If I were B I would expect at least an apology for reneging on the promise, regardless of the professor's reason for reneging.

Comment: I must confess that _I_ would have been unable to imagine that the requestor was the "bad" student, but instead would have powerfully presumed that it was the "good" student... and would have been dumbfounded for many reasons if/when the "bad" student showed up at my door. For one, I would have been completely confused as to what such a student imagined I'd write in a letter for them. In particular, it would baffle me if they claimed that they'd thought that I could somehow write a non-fatal letter, based on reality. I'd "apologize" in only the most perfunctory way... srsly...

Comment: It is certainly a reasonable mistake to make, but that doesn't mean the professor didn't make the mistake, and it's pretty standard to apologize for accidents.  Actually I'm pretty dumbfounded that the prevailing opinion on this site is "how DARE the student ask for a letter from ME" rather than "yeah the professor screwed up, he should apologize for accidentally misleading the student."

Comment: IMO this is symptomatic of a larger trend in academia where professors feel entitled to treat their students like shit.  Because they have so much power, they can easily get away with treating students however they want to, so they forget to act like decent human beings much of the time (and often they've internalized it so much that they *don't know they're doing it*).  I am very fortunate to have found an advisor who is not a shithead, and this fact alone makes me enthusiastically sing his praises to all new students in my department

Comment: There is nothing in the question implying the professor did not apologise. If someone here fails to be a decent human being, it is student B, who apparently has difficulty taking no for an answer, regardless of how it is presented.

Comment: @fkraiem You're right, the professor may have apologized, in which case I think it's the best he can do in this unfortunate situation.  Also, the student definitely should not have complained to the department head.  It just bugs me that the prevailing opinion on this site is that the professor doesn't owe the student *anything*, even an acknowledgement of his mistakes.

Comment: There is a huge difference between refusing to hurt the student and treating the student as shit. And the prevailing opinion on the side is not "how dare the student ask for a letter from me" but "why would the student ask for a reference letter when he should expect a negative one"...

Comment: You are right: the professor owes something to the student: a bad reference letter.

Comment: The argument in the 1st paragraph and the comments borders on ridiculous. The was no abuse of power on the side of the Prof. It is the student who clearly doesn't know how to behave. And it is the student who should have apologized for his behaviour (the student was naughty in multiple classes ...).

Comment: There are lots of reasons.  Maybe the student actually thinks the professor likes him for some reason, or he knows he did poorly in the class but he did even worse in other people's classes.

Comment: @choener: I would not call this an "abuse of power," but it's symptomatic of the general attitude that because someone is a powerful professor, they need not show basic courtesy to their students.

Comment: "Basic courtesy" is not "writing a good letter when none is merited". Sure, there is a huge power asymmetry, and power is often abused, that does not seem to be a dominant feature here, or even entering at all. Sure, the situation is awkward, but letter writers should not allow themselves to be coerced by embarrassment into giving false references. Again, "I'm terribly sorry, I stupidly thought you were someone else... when I agreed to write a letter." is a civil response. How can the student be "angry"? "Disappointed", conceivably, but even that seems to require a disconnect from reality.

Comment: Oh, I didn't say he should write the letter; in fact, it is good that he didn't.  I just don't like the attitude of "how dare the student ask for a letter," "the student tried to deceive the professor on purpose," and "the professor is always right."  Not just on this thread, but in general.

Comment: Ben, I think people were mostly saying that it was operationally not even remotely _sensible_ for the student to ask, since there could have been no reasonable expectation of a helpful letter. A merely less-awful letter is still fatal, for almost any purpose. The anger is hard to figure out, because I cannot visualize what the student thought would happen, either way. I think this particular question was not too much about the (enormous, occasionally abused) power differential.

Comment: Ben the attitude is not "how dare he ask for a letter" but is puzzlement: "why would he ask for a letter given the circumstances". There is no way he can get a good letter....

Comment: "Maybe the student actually thinks the professor likes him for some reason, or he knows he did poorly in the class but he did even worse in other people's classes. " <---Sorry, I completely disagree... You should never ask from a letter from a professor if the only interaction is negative...And if the only recommendation letter one can get is a negative letter, then one should know better than ask...

Comment: I dunno, in my experience most professors are really tactful, so in some cases it's hard to tell that a professor doesn't like you.  At any rate the student may have been poorly advised.  For instance maybe he thought he should ask the most famous professor he knew, or the one whose class was most relevant to his intended field of study, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The questions-not-asked include asking about the basis for student B's actions. As @BenBitdiddle comments after his answer, perhaps student B was "advised" to ask the most famous professor, etc.

My blanket reaction to this is that this advice should not have come from any professionally competent "advisor", but probably from peers, or peer-based information. Abstractly, there's certainly nothing wrong with getting the opinions of one's friends and peers. However, it is exactly in such situations that the critical weakness in asking people who don't know much about a given thing is instantiated. How to know that this would be a problem? Difficult, for many understandable reasons, but that does not resolve the issue!

That is, younger people would benefit from appreciating the palpable fact that important decisions affecting their lives are made by people (often older) who need not share their viewpoint, nor their same-age friends' viewpoint.

While it is true that some people who "have power" abuse it, this is not a universal, and it is not wise to postulate that all experienced/older people are oppressive or selfish. Genuine experience, as opposed to conjecture, is hard to replace. Thus, ideally, letter-of-recommendation writers are sufficiently experienced to have been through (and succeeded in) the endeavor for which they're writing a letter. Perhaps also experience (and successful in) appraising the likely future success of people in those endeavors. From this comes the value of letters of recommendation.

Yes, unfortunately, even a pretty-darn-good performance in a routine course doesn't give a letter writer much to work with. Many people hit that mark, etc.

What's a student to do who has trashed all those bridges, before they realized that it'd matter? Probably spend extra time proving exactly that they'd caught on, and have moved to a different plateau. But there'd need to be tangible evidence, not just a promise.

So, in effect, "tell your friends not to hope for letters from faculty in whose courses they'd done badly"... And, if people discover themselves in the position that there's no alternative, then they need to get as close to a "do-over" as they can, because otherwise they've sealed their own fate, in any conventional avenue.

Yes, it is indeed unfortunate that this "appraisal" period comes during a period of peoples' lives where many things are in turmoil...

So, again, people who become aware of this mechanism should "tell their friends" to work hard to avoid finding themselves in such a situation. If one does, then it is almost surely better to allocate considerable time to repair the damage, rather than somehow "fake it" and limp along with fatally bad letters of recommendation.

By the way, part of the "currency" that faculty have to spend (or not) is their word/reputation, so they are very, very hesitant to blow it on bogus not-so-bad recommendations. Faculty who'll give glowing recommendations to nearly anyone will have debased that currency to an extent that it is nearly worthless... so you'd not gain from a letter from them *anyway*.

Answer (score 3):

Semi-serious answer:

---

**As student B:** Next time, claim a family emergency and ask whether the prof can please send you the letter of recommendation. As much as you liked to see him in person, you're at home caring for your dying grandmother (again). (And drop this case, you're getting an even worse reputation.)

**As better student B:** Don't ask for a letter of recommendation from a prof if you did show abysmal behavior and performance in class. It's a letter of recommendation, not cronyism, there should be something to recommend.

**As an even better student B:** Behave better in class and learn to learn (and to perform). University isn't school and you're supposed to be an adult by now -- you actually have a job: to learn the material, to understand it, and to learn how to think. And BTW, there's a place for naughty behavior in class -- *if it's smart*. But that requires understanding the material, which according to the grades B did not.

---

**As prof Z:** Apologize that you have written the wrong letter of recommendation, which was a honest mistake. Ask the student whether s/he really wants a letter of recommendation which essentially states that s/he was in class, disrupted it and got bad grades (if it's legally possible to write about negative events)

**As a better prof Z:** Never write a letter of recommendation without checking first for whom you are writing the letter of recommendation. Ask for the identifying information that differentiated between the students when it came to assigning their grades. If students failed to understand their job, they might fail to understand what is involved in getting a letter of recommendation.

**As an even better prof Z:** If you have a student B in your class, try to inform this person about the consequences of his/her behavior. And that in earlier schools, everyone might have been a winner, but here good grades require knowledge/skills/performance. Also inform administration that you have a student apparently riding on the coattails of another student. Every prof who had both students in their class should get this information.

---

**As student A:** Never give student B your diplomas.

**As a better student A:** Ask prof Z. for that letter of recommendation.

**As an even better student A:** Legally change (add to) your name.

Comment: _As prof Z: Apologize that you have written the wrong letter of recommendation_, I don't think Prof. Z actually wrote the recommendation letter based on the OP's description.

Comment: Agreed. I read it as if the prof already did the work, but it seems he "only" promised to do it. Waow, even worse. Overall, the lack of reflection is what would kill writing a reference letter for student B for me.